# why is it hard to determine whether a given string belongs to $X$ or not for a set of strings $X$ is defined by an inductive definition

Tags: induction

I do not understand the answer to this question

Question: If a set  of strings $X$ is defined by an inductive definition, then it is:

Answer: easy to generate elements of $X$ but hard to determine whether a given string belongs to $X$ or not

why would it be hard to determine a whether a given string belongs to $X$ or not, I cant seem to think of a reason why

Comment: I commend to your attention the book *Gödel, Escher, Bach*, and specifically the [MU puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle). Think about the puzzle ("turn the string `MI` into the string `MU` using the given transformation rules") without looking at the solution.

Comment: Because you have to devise all the steps of the process that produces it (if it is correctly produced).